# functx:remove-attributes adds an empty xmlns

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, functx

The function [functx:remove-attributes](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_remove-attributes.html) adds automatically an empty *@xmlns* to the node and I would like to prevent this behavior.
Example xml:

```
<mei meiversion="3.0.0" xmlns="http://www.music-encoding.org/ns/mei">
<note accid.ges="f" doxml.id="d28e18935" dur="8" oct="4" pname="e" tstamp="1.75" xml:id="note_112296"/>
</mei>
```

XSLT excerpt:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="functx:remove-attributes(., $attributes2remove)" />
```

Current (false) XML output:

```
<note accid.ges="f" doxml.id="d28e18935" dur="8" oct="4" pname="e" tstamp="1.75" xml:id="note_112296" xmlns=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function body, I think you want to use `xsl:copy` instead of `xsl:element`:

```
<xsl:function name="functx:remove-attributes" as="element()"
              xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:param name="elements" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:param name="names" as="xs:string*"/>

   <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:sequence
         select="(@*[not(functx:name-test(name(),$names))],
                 node())"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:function>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJrP